# first excerpt fine, subsequent post excerpts shift to the right instead of displaying vertically

Tags: theme-development, loop, themes, excerpt

The front page of the blog is intended to show post excerpts and a cropped version of the post image. The first/most recent excerpt is perfect, however the older subsequent excerpts are showing up somewhat shifted to the right. I'm thinking the problem lies in my loop, but I've been looking at it for so long I think a pair of fresh eyes is needed.

index.php-

```
<?php echo get_header();;?>
<?php echo get_sidebar();;?>

<div id="blog">
    <div class="preview">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post-image">
            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-image' );
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="post">
            <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
            <span class="post-preview">
                <?php the_excerpt('read more...'); ?>
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                    <p>Sorry, no posts to list</p>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </span><!-- end post-preivew -->
            <p class="post-meta"><span style="font-family: amatic;">>></span>&nbsp;Posted on <?php the_date('M-d-y'); ?>&nbsp;<span style="font-family: amatic;">>></span>&nbsp;<?php the_tags('tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?></p><!-- end post-meta -->
        </div><!-- end post -->
    </div><!-- end preview -->
</div><!-- end blog -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: you open tags inside of your loop but close them outside of it.

Comment: @Milo What do you mean?

Comment: a `while` loop repeats what's inside the loop before the `endwhile`. you open html tags, like `<div class="post">` inside the loop, but close them outside. look at where `</div><!-- end post -->` is in relation to where you opened it, it's after the `endwhile`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments yet, but do you get what Milo is saying?

Just look at this section and it is as if there are no closing  or  tags for the classes post and post-preview.

```
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post-image">
                <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-image' );
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
                <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
                <span class="post-preview">
                    <?php the_excerpt('read more...'); ?>
                            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
```